# will performance of website be affected due to having no MVC architecture?

Tags: php, web-services

I have a php web app. But i have kept all the program files(css, html, php, js) in a single folder. I have not given architecture like MVC. Will this affect the performance of the website, and slows down the application?? Little puzzled. It will be great if anyone can give an explanatory.
Thanks!

Comment: Not at all, it only permit to work on precise point of a program, so more than one person can update the code, and for maintenance matters. Knowing the speed of the code going through folders to bring a variable, it is not the main consequence of latency in a website.

Comment: its a good practise to use MVC model for manage you data and also for code files. For example in the past you want change only view then you should only look into view code. and it is very easy to understand the code for third person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as far as I know it has no effect on application performance. Take css definitions for example:

```
<link href="assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="assets/stylesheets/jquery_ui/jquery.ui-1.10.0.custom.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This has no benefit nor disadvantage regarding website performance compared to this

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="bootstrap-responsive.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="jquery.ui-1.10.0.custom.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Same thing goes for the `script` files. The only downside of storing everything in a single folder is that you will probably spend some extra time looking for the file you need.

On the other hand there are some best practices to study. Take a look at [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

if only talking about performance, most mvc frameworks like the one i am using [yiiframework](http://www.yiiframework.com/) has caching mechanism and various plugins to compress js and css. So personally i dont think mvc structure impacts the performance, but the extra stuffs packed with mvc frameworks.